# Blender- Glare node not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am using a glare node and it is doesn't seem to be effecting my rendered image at all. Does anyone know why this is?

Ive included my node set up with the glare node connected and without
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to lower the threshold value on the glare node until the threshold is below the value of the light you want to glow.

Comment: You're running Glare on the emission pass.  Are you sure you're getting any effect from that?  Set Glare's mix setting to 1 and look at it through the viewer.

Comment: Your Composite and Viewer node are also receiving different inputs.  That may not be important just yet, but something to look out for on final output.

Comment: @AllenSimpson https://we.tl/t-pAvv8wEQ0x heres a link to just a cube and light with a glare node, I simplified the scene but still can't get it to work. Would you mind checking it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

1. The main problem is that you have the emissive pass hooked up to the glare node. This results the glare only applying when emissive surfaces that are directly visible to the camera. This means reflected and transmitted light will not receive the glare effect.

- To fix this, you should use the denoised image as the input for the glare node.

2. The structure of your node tree indicates that you wish to control the strength of the glare effect by adjusting the 'Fac' (factor) for the Add (Mix) node. However, you need to change the 'Mix' parameter on the Glare node so that you you are only adding the glare effect and not adding the image with the glare applied.

- To fix this, set the 'Mix' parameter of the Glare node to 1.

After doing these two fixes, you may need to adjust the threshold parameter (as others have suggested) depending on the intensity of light in your scene.

[image: Example of proper compositor node tree setup.]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i don't whether this is the effect you want, but you can see a difference at least:

[image]